# I am getting exception while reading pop3 mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a problem while reading pop3 mail

and my code is very simple..

```
Properties objServerProp = new Properties();
objServerProp.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "pop3");
objServerProp.setProperty("mail.host", "xxx.xx-ip.org");
objServerProp.put("imap.mail.port", "110");
objServerProp.put("imap.mail.auth", "true");

Session  objSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(objServerProp, null);
Store instStore = objSession.getStore("pop3");
instStore.connect("xxx.xx-ip.org", Integer.valueOf(110), "id", "pwd");
Folder  objFolder = instStore.getFolder("inbox");
objFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
int count = objFolder.getMessageCount();

 Message objMessage = objFolder.getMessage(1);
 System.out.println("objMessage is :: "+objMessage);
 System.out.println("  message contenttype :: " + objMessage.getContentType());
```

when i am calling any method ( like :getContentType() ) on message object i am getting below exception,,,

and the message object is coming fine as

```
objMessage is :: com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message@37d8d2
```

Exception is below..

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: error loading POP3 headers;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: Unexpected response: 
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message.loadHeaders(POP3Message.java:467)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message.getSize(POP3Message.java:106)
    at in10sbouncemailtracker.BMTServer.checkBouncedMails(BMTServer.java:232)
    at BMTMain.main(BMTMain.java:18)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected response: 
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.simpleCommand(Protocol.java:361)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.multilineCommand(Protocol.java:373)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.top(Protocol.java:271)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message.loadHeaders(POP3Message.java:451)
... 3 more
```

Comment: Really - you didn't get an answer with in a minute and you are already bugging?

Comment: Which is line number 18 here??

Comment: 18 line is in caller method, problem is in called method and
 problem is while calling any method on objMessage object..
  
 when i calling objMessage.getContentType() i am getting above exceptions

Answer (score 0):

As described in the JavaMail FAQ, [turn on session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).  The protocol trace will show you what the unexpected response is.  You should also look at the [properties described in the com.sun.mail.pop3 package javadocs](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html), some of them might be useful for working around bugs in your server.